# Validação de dois selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho dois campos `select`, um eu tenho estados e outro cidades. Preciso selecionar em um `select` um estado, ex: São Paulo e no outro `select` trazer somente as cidades de são paulo.

Comment: Você já tem o banco de dados dos estados e cidades ?

Comment: e o que você tentou fazer? mostre o seu código para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Tem várias perguntas aqui no `stackoverflow PT` abordando esse tema... você tem algum mecanismo de `back-end`? Onde você salva os valores das cidades e estados? Tem alguma tabela com as relações? Qual o banco de dados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partindo do príncipio que você estará trabalhando com dados do tipo JSON, mas pode ser em qualquer formato... você pode obter o evento `onchange` no `select` de estados, e aplicar um [filtro](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) no vetor de cidades, buscando por cidades que possui o estado selecionado. Algo como isso:

```js
var arrayDeCidades = [
  {"nome":"Bauru", "estado":"sp" },
  {"nome":"Ourinhos", "estado":"sp" },
  {"nome":"Curitiba", "estado":"pr" }
];

document.getElementById("estados").onchange = function(){
  var selCidades = document.getElementById("cidades");
  selCidades.innerHTML = "";
  var cidadesFiltradas = arrayDeCidades.filter(cidade =>{
    return cidade.estado == this.value;
  });
  cidadesFiltradas.forEach(cidade =>{
    var optionInc = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optionInc.innerHTML = cidade.nome;
    selCidades.appendChild(optionInc);
  });
  
}
```

```html
Estado:
<select id="estados">
  <option>Selecione</option>
  <option value="sp">São Paulo</option>
  <option value="pr">Paraná</option>
</select>

Cidade:
<select id="cidades">

</select>
```

A forma que você irá carregar o combo de estados e a origem dos dados de cidades depende da sua base de dados (SQL, Ws que retorna um JSON, não sei).