# Mudar um select baseado na seleção de outro select (a partir de dados no BD)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Em um formulário, eu preciso fazer a seleção de um FABRICANTE, e de acordo com essa seleção, ele mostrar os PRODUTOS vinculados a esse fabricante apenas.

Eu tenho as seguinte tabela onde eu cadastro o FABRICANTE:

```
FABRICANTES:
id_fabricante | nome_fabricante
     1        |     CANON
```

E tenho a tabela CÂMERAS, onde eu faço a vinculação do FABRICANTE ao modelo da câmera

```
CAMERAS:
id_camera | fabricantes_id_fabricante (chave estrangeira) | modelo_camera
1         |            CANON                              |   5D MARK II
```

Agora que entra a parte complicada, eu criei o `form` onde ele puxa com PHP no banco de dados os fabricantes cadastrados:

```
<?php
$fabricantes = listaFabricantes($conexao);
?>
   ...
    <tr>
    <td>Fabricante:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="fabricantes_id_fabricante" id="fabricantes_id_fabricante" class="form-control">
    <?php
foreach ($fabricantes as $fabricante):
?>
   <option value="<?= $fabricante['id_fabricante'] ?>">
    <?= $fabricante['nome_fabricante'] ?></br></option> 
    <?php
endforeach;
?>
   </td> 


    </tr>
    ...
```

E depois criei o form que lista as câmeras:

```
<tr>
<td>Linha de Câmera:</td>
<td>
<select name="cameras_linhas_id_camera_linha" id="cameras_linhas_id_camera_linha" class="form-control">
<?php foreach($cameras_linhas as $camera_linha) :?>
<option value="<?=$camera_linha['id_camera_linha']?>">
<?=$camera_linha['nome_linha_camera']?></br></option> 
<?php endforeach?>
</td> 
</tr>
```

Só que o que eu quero fazer agora é quando eu selecionar o fabricante CANON ele só apareça as câmeras que tem o relacionamento com esse fabricante, e não que liste todas as câmeras.

O mais próximo que eu consegui fazer isso, foi utilizando o Jquery da seguinte maneira:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>‌​
<script>
$('#fabricantes_id_fabricante').change(function(){
   selection = $(this).val();    
   switch(selection)
   { 
       case '1':
           $('#cameras_linhas_id_camera_linha').show();
           break;
       default:
           $('#cameras_linhas_id_camera_linha').hide();
           break;
   }
});
</script>
```

Mas nesse caso acima, só funciona caso as opções dos SELECTS sejam criados no form html e não buscando do banco de dados a ligação.

Sei que está um pouco extenso, mas alguém poderia ajudar com uma ideia de como poderia fazer essa consulta do Jquery no bd para retornar os resultados ou alguma outra luz?

Seria algo parecido com o que fazem de Estado x Cidade, onde clica em determinado estado e só aparecem as respectivas cidades, e essas informações serem buscadas de um banco de dados. Já estou a alguns dias quebrando a cabeça, por isso recorri aqui.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Para simplicar podes colocar o HTML que tem quando a página carrega? já tens os dois select com as options todas, ou um dos select deve mudar as option consoante o primeiro?

Comment: Vou postar um exemplo que tenho usando Ajax, deve te ajudar.

Comment: Respondi uma pergunta com a mesma dúvida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162062/valida%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-dois-selects/162066#162066. A única diferença é que no `change` deverá ser feito a consulta por ajax no PHP para obter a lista de câmeras e então criar o segundo `select`.

Comment: @Sergio o que eu gostaria é que listasse as informações do SELECT1 e de acordo com esse select, aparecessem as opções do SELECT2. Como se fosse a relação de País x Estado. Tenhos os países Brasil e Portugal no SELECT1, quando eu seleciono Brasil, aparece SP, RJ, etc. Mas gostaria que todas essas informações viessem do banco de dados, sem eu ter que criar os options no form.

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Não coloque "RESOLVIDO" no título, e crie você mesmo uma resposta com a sua solução (ao invés de editar e colocá-la no corpo da pergunta). Este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia a [help], ok? :)

Comment: Não coloque a resposta dentro da pergunta. Confunde e atrapalha...

Comment: Pronto, coloquei como resposta. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos!

Comment: Por nada! :) Vc também não precisa agradecer no corpo das respostas. A melhor forma de agradecer alguém que te ajudou é votando nas respostas deles. E também considere aceitar uma resposta para indicar para futuros leitores aquela que mais te ajudou ou que de fato resolveu o seu problema. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****Consegui resolver da seguinte forma****

Fiz o exemplo com estados e cidades pois acredito que seja mais fácil da compreensão de qual era o problema e qual é a solução:

**index.php**

```
?>
<?php
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_selectdb('banco_teste');

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_estados ORDER BY nome_estado");
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Atualizando combos com jquery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#estado').change(function(){
            $('#cidade').load('listaCidades.php?estado='+$('#estado').val());
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Atualizando combos com jquery</h1>
    <label>Estado:</label>
    <select name="estado" id="estado">
    <?php while($reg = mysql_fetch_object($rs)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $reg->id_estado ?>"><?php echo $reg->nome_estado ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="cidade"></div>
  </body>
</html>


<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/admin/skin/footer/footer.php";?>
```

**listaCidades.php**

```
 <?php 
  require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/admin/includes/connect.php";


$id_estado = $_GET['estado'];

$rs = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM tbl_cidades WHERE id_estado = '$id_estado' ORDER BY nome_cidade");

echo "<label>Cidades: </label><select name='cidade'>";
while($reg = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)){
    echo "<option value='$reg->id_cidade'>$reg->nome_cidade</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

**jquery-1.6.4.js**
E eu baixei o seguinte arquivo js e salvei na pasta que estão os outros arquivos: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos!

Comment: Foi feito uso do Ajax para funcionar??

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

O que tu precisas para o teu caso é de uma chamada de uma página em **AJAX** por exemplo, que receba os dados que pretendes pesquisar.

Quando mudares a opção da tua selectbox ele faz a chamada AJAX para actualizar as opções de outro selectbox:

HTML

```
<select id="fabricante">
    <option value="1">Canon</option>
    <option value="2">Nikon</option>
</select>

<select id="modelo"></select>
```

JS

```
$('select#fabricante').on("change", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: example.php,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#modelo').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Nota: O Ficheiro **example.php** é que trata de substituir o selectbox que já existe no html, deves criar outro select lá com as novas opções que vais receber no GET do AJAX.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Antonio. Essas informações de fabricantes e seus respectivos modelos já estão inseridas e relacionados em uma tabela no banco de dados. É listei os fabricantes no código que eu enviei acima, é possível a partir dessa minha listagem do banco de dados, pegar os dados relacionados da tabela sem ter que criar as opções no form?

Comment: Olá sim é possível, através de um INNER JOIN por exemplo na query, o melhor é ver o exemplo do @ivcs

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro que use AJAX, onde ficaria assim:

No **front-end**:

```
<form>

<input name='fabricante' type='number'>

<select name='produto'>

</select>

<button>Enviar</button>

</form>

<p></p>

<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(function(){


    $('input[name=fabricante]').keyup(function(){ 
        $('select').empty();
        var id = $('input[name=fabricante]').val();
        $.ajax({ // ajax
            type: "POST",
            url: "seleciona_produtos.php",
            data: { fabricante : id }, 
            success: function(result) {
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                console.debug(result);

                if(result.success) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.produtos.length; i++) {
                        $('select').append('<option value="' + result.produtos[i].id + '">' + result.produtos[i].nome + "</option>");
                    }
                } else {
                    $('p').text('nao encontrado');
                }

            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Tenho um formulário, nele tem o fabricante (no seu caso é um `select`) que é um número, onde será o `ID` daquele fabricante, ao alterar o valor dele, envio um *ajax* para uma página *PHP*, pegando o retorno, se houver produtos nele, adiciono ele ao `select` do formulário, se não só digo que não encontrou.

No **back-end**:

```
<?php 

$produtos = [
    ['id' => 1, 'fabricante' => 1, 'nome' => 'mouse'],
    ['id' => 2, 'fabricante' => 2, 'nome' => 'teclado'],
    ['id' => 3, 'fabricante' => 2, 'nome' => 'monitor'],
    ['id' => 4, 'fabricante' => 3, 'nome' => 'carregador'],
    ['id' => 5, 'fabricante' => 1, 'nome' => 'webcam'],
    ['id' => 6, 'fabricante' => 4, 'nome' => 'microfone'],
];

if(count($_POST) > 0) {

    $_POST['fabricante'] = (int)$_POST['fabricante'];
    $resultado = ['success' => true];


    foreach ($produtos as $value)
        if($value['fabricante'] == $_POST['fabricante'])
            $resultado['produtos'][] = $value;

    if(count($resultado) > 1)
        die(json_encode($resultado));
}

die(json_encode('[message : "erro", success: false]'));
?>
```

Tenho um `array` de produtos, que simula todos os produtos no banco de dados, após isso percorro o esse `array`, olhando qual tema aquele fabricante (simulando o `SELECT` do *SQL*), vou colocando os produtos dessa fabricante em um *array* de resultados, por fim retorno o resultado como `JSON` para o *front-end* que pega esse resultado e coloca no *select* do formulário.

Mas caso ainda prefira deixar todos os produtos escondidos no HTML, use:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
 <select name='fabricante'>
  <option value='1'>Fabricante 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Fabricante 2</option>
  <option value='3'>Fabricante 3</option>
 </select>

 <select name='produtos'>
 </select>

 <div class="hidden produtos-f1">
  <option value='11'>Mouse</option>
  <option value='31'>Teclado</option>
  <option value='41'>Monitor</option>
 </div>

 <div class="hidden produtos-f2">
  <option value='23'>Processador</option>
  <option value='43'>HD</option>
  <option value='12'>Memoria RAM</option>
  <option value='51'>Bateria</option>
 </div>

 <div class="hidden produtos-f3">
  <option value='1'>Notebook</option>
 </div>
</form>

<script>
$(function(){

 $('.hidden').hide();
  
  $('select[name=produtos]').html($('div.produtos-f1').html());
 

 $('select[name=fabricante]').change(function(){ 
  var id = $('select[name=fabricante]').val();

  $('select[name=produtos]').empty();
  
  $('select[name=produtos]').html($('div.produtos-f' + id).html());

 });
 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Deixa eu tirar outra dúvida, nesse seu exemplo, eu faço a listagem dos ID FABRICANTE  e relaciono com os produtos de cada fabricante. Mas isso seria possível apenas puxando o relacionamento a partir de uma tabela do banco de dados? Exemplo, eu já tenho no banco uma tabela que me diz que o FABRICANTE 1 fabrica MOUSE. É possível a partir dessa informação no banco de dados o SELECT 1 após listar o FABRICANTE 1, mostrar o MOUSE? Sem ter que fazer esse array?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua dúvida, talvez a segunda maneira que eu coloquei seja como você esta falando, onde peguei o resultado dos produtos separados por fabricantes e para cada fabricante criei uma div oculta com seus produtos..

Comment: MAs usando o primeiro método, o array seria trocado por um SELECT no banco de dados, por exemplo SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE fabricante = $_POST['fabricante']

Comment: A melhor opção é a primeira, vou tentar aqui trocar o array pelo select no banco de dados e já dou um retorno para ver se funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: Pq na verdade, eu já tenho os valores no banco de dados, não quero preenche-los em um HTML. Quero selecionar o valores do banco, e de acordo com a seleção que eu fiz no SELECT1 ele me mostrar as opções do SELECT2.

Comment: Ok, qualquer coisa pode perguntar.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, coloquei como resposta como resolvi o problema!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que seria melhor fazer por SQL. Selecionar todas as câmeras onde o fabricante está relacionado como chave estrangeira da outra tabela.

Algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM cameras, fabricante WHERE fabricante.nome = cameras.id_fabricante_nome
```